# Select specific quantity of li in ul block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an ul-block in which there are 15 li positions.

First 5 li-s are pre-shown, another 10 are hidden. I have a function that toggles this UL - and if I click the button - it shows that 10 li-s but hides first 5.

I need such jQuery selector, so that the 5 first can be visible every time and not be toggling.
This piece of code selects all of them

```
var ul = $(this).parent().attr('class');
 $('.'+ul+' li').toggle();
```

If there a way to select all except the first 5?

Comment: you should show your `ul` structure.

Comment: something like :nth-of-type(n+6); as your selector

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: @Stender Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when you're right, you're right - that is a bit more comprehensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this:

1) You can use the [slice function](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```js
$("ul li").slice(5).hide();
$('button').click(function(e) {
  $("ul li").slice(5).toggle().addClass('redText');
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.redText {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> 1 </li>
  <li> 2 </li>
  <li> 3 </li>
  <li> 4 </li>
  <li> 5 </li>
  <li> 6 </li>
  <li> 7 </li>
  <li> 8 </li>
  <li> 9 </li>
  <li> 10 </li>
  <li> 11 </li>
  <li> 12 </li>
  <li> 13 </li>
  <li> 14 </li>
  <li> 15 </li>
</ul>
<button> click </button>
```

2) **Or** you can use the jQuery [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) (greater than) selector

```js
$("ul li:gt(4)").hide();
$('button').click(function(e) {
  $("ul li:gt(4)").toggle().addClass('redText');
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.redText {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li> 1 </li>
  <li> 2 </li>
  <li> 3 </li>
  <li> 4 </li>
  <li> 5 </li>
  <li> 6 </li>
  <li> 7 </li>
  <li> 8 </li>
  <li> 9 </li>
  <li> 10 </li>
  <li> 11 </li>
  <li> 12 </li>
  <li> 13 </li>
  <li> 14 </li>
  <li> 15 </li>
</ul>
<button> click </button>
```

---

### Final Update

Just an aside to your comment below this answer, I have added one final code snippet that should hopefully answer your question completely.

```js
//your function to fade in li past index 5
$.fn.myFunc = function(ul, event) {
  $('.' + ul + ' li:gt(4)').fadeToggle("fast");
};

//Add a button to the ul
$('.list').append('<button type="button" id="updateButton">Button</button>');

//button click event
$('#updateButton').on("click", function(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var myParameter = $(this).parent().attr("class");
  $(this).myFunc(myParameter, e);
});
```

```css
.listitem-green{
  color: green;
}

.listitem-red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="listitem-green"> 1 </li>
  <li class="listitem-green"> 2 </li>
  <li class="listitem-green"> 3 </li>
  <li class="listitem-green"> 4 </li>
  <li class="listitem-green"> 5 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 6 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 7 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 8 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 9 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 10 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 11 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 12 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 13 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 14 </li>
  <li class="listitem-red"> 15 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By the way, maybe you can advice something to avoid screen down to the bottom of the browser after toggling?

Comment: @JohnathanFidelio Sure, try `preventDefault();` I already updated both examples with this, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have such syntax. Here is my code
I am sorry, but frankly, i dont know where to put it. You see, i dont have this "e" parameter.
`$.fn.myFunc = function() { var ul=$(this).parent().attr('class');`
`$('.'+ul+' li:gt(5)').fadeToggle("fast"); };`


`$('.ul' + l).append('<button type="button" `  `onclick="$(this).myFunc()">Button</button>');`
Maybe you can advice where to put this preventDefault?

Comment: @JohnathanFidelio Check my update. Hopefully it will answer your question.

Comment: unfortunately it didnt. I created 
`window.location = at.attr('href');` to hold block position but i doesnt see the anchor

Answer (score 2):

Because of the CSS tag below the question, here is a full CSS snippet.

```css
/* hide */
#tgl:checked ~ul li:nth-child(5) ~li, #tgl {display: none; }
/* update label text */
#tgl:checked~[for="tgl"]:after             {content:' More'}
#tgl~[for="tgl"]:after                     {content:' Less'}
/*style label, easy demo */
label {appearance:button;-moz-appearance:button; /* Firefox */-webkit-appearance:button; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="tgl" checked/>
<ul>
  <li> 1 </li>
  <li> 2 </li>
  <li> 3 </li>
  <li> 4 </li>
  <li> 5 </li>
  <li> 6 </li>
  <li> 7 </li>
  <li> 8 </li>
  <li> 9 </li>
  <li> 10 </li>
  <li> 11 </li>
  <li> 12 </li>
  <li> 13 </li>
  <li> 14 </li>
  <li> 15 </li>
</ul>
<label for="tgl"> Show </label>
```

styling is triggered via the input state and the selector `:nth-child() ~`

Switching style can be made from : `input ~ul li:nth-child(5) ~ li {/*any style*/}` or  `input:checked ~ul li:nth-child(5) ~ li {/*any other style when input checked*/}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ulClass li:gt(5)").hide();
  $('.clickMe').click(function() {
    $(".ulClass li:gt(5)").toggle();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class='ulClass'>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
</ol>
<button class='clickMe'>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing snippet to show it with a css selector instead of jQuery

```js
$('ul > li:nth-of-type(n+6)').addClass('redText');
```

```css
.redText
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li> 1 </li>
  <li> 2 </li>
  <li> 3 </li>
  <li> 4 </li>
  <li> 5 </li>
  <li> 6 </li>
  <li> 7 </li>
  <li> 8 </li>
  <li> 9 </li>
  <li> 10 </li>
  <li> 11 </li>
  <li> 12 </li>
  <li> 13 </li>
  <li> 14 </li>
  <li> 15 </li>
</ul>
```